# Array values disappear after executing case statement VBA (excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am trying to save the background color of a group of cells in a 2D array so that when "Case 1 To 2" is triggered, the cell background colors should be stored in WaferArr. The problem is, WaferArr values disappear (return 0 for all values) after "Case 1 To 2" executes. Any ideas on why this is would happen are appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Range("A1:F22").Interior.ColorIndex = 2

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim WaferArr(21, 5) As Integer
    
    k = 13
    
    'If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target) And Target.Address = "$I$6" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case 1 To 2:
            For i = 0 To 5
                For j = k To 21
                    WaferArr(j, i) = Cells(j + 1, i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex
                Next j
                
                If i = 2 Then
                    k = 0
                End If
            Next i
            
            Range("D1:F22").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            Range("A14:C22").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        Case Is < 1
            For i = 0 To 5
                For j = k To 21
                    Cells(j + 1, i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = WaferArr(j, i)
                Next j
                
                If i = 2 Then
                    k = 0
                End If
            Next i
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

WaferArr values are still stored after the last *End If* before *End Sub*. I insert *MsgBox WaferArr(0,0)* after "*k = 13*" and *WaferArr* always returns 0. When *"Case Is < 1"* executes, all *WaferArr* values are 0.

Comment: That's the definition of local variables: They will be gone after the routine is finished. Next time the routine is called, they are brand new variables and VBA will initialise them. So either use a global variable or declare it as `Static`